# PHP command buttons that run Python script passed through AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, ajax

I am still battling through learning AJAX and various ways to implement.   I have a DIV tag on my website which I’m using AJAX to dynamically update after 5 seconds (timed update is for unrelated reasons) by reloading a status.php file into the DIV tag.

The problem I’m having is when I directly browse the status.php the command buttons work properly, however when I use them through the index.php they do not respond.

I am trying to learn why they fail this way and what I can to make in work in an “ELI5” kind of way.

The command buttons run a Python script which opens/closes the garage door.  The next time the status Python script (at the top of status.php) is run, it'll have the new status of the door and eventually display it in the DIV tags when AJAX updates that part of the page.

When I click the buttons now index.php stays displayed in it, but the DIV tag completely reloads status.php.   When this happens though, the Python script does not appear to get triggered.

I suspect the command buttons need to be run in a more AJAX/Java-ey way instead of through PHP, but I don't even know where to begin.

Oh, one more thing:    I also have a CGI script available (e.h.  http://example.com/cgi-bin/myq-cgi.py?username=user&pass=pass&command=open) which I can also use to open/close the door.   I do NOT use it for the status though because it doesn't include the time/date the status last changed like the full Python script does.  This might be a potential way to better open/close the door.

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){ 
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "status.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#status_div").html('The Garage Door Status is: ' + data);
                    }
                })

            }, 5000);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Somethign on the web page.  Normally this would be the main website while the DIV tag waits to load.
        <div id="status_div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

status.php:

```
<?php

// Call Python script which gives me the status of my garage door in a text string.
$output = shell_exec('python /home/blah/garage_door/myq-garage.py status');

//I am NOT including lots of parsing of the $output.  Eventually I get the $output trimmed down to the to the $status PHP variable.
$status[1] = "Closed"   //values here can be either 'Closed' or 'Open'

?>

<!-- // Style info for table(s) -->
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:7px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:7px 7px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;wor$
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:center;text-align:left}
</style>

<!-- // HTML table to display garage door status info.  Display the image of the door and door status in left cell, time/date and options in right -->
<center>
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh">
        <div class="garage_status">
            <?php
                //Stuff unrelated to OP question here.  Dynamically displaying an image based on garage door status.
             ?>
        </div>
    </th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">
        <?php
            // Command button to open door.
            if (isset($_POST['button_open'])){
                if ($status[1] = "Closed"){
                    shell_exec('python /home/blah/garage_door/myq-garage.py open "Garage Door"');
                }
            }

            // Command button to close door.
                if (isset($_POST['button_close'])){
                    if ($status[1] = "Open"){
                        shell_exec('python /home/blah/garage_door/myq-garage.py close "Garage Door"');
                        echo "<script>alert (\"cmd button works\")</script>";
                    }
                }

        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                <button name="button_open">Open Door</button>
                <button name="button_close">Close Door</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </th>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: you can not fire an event within your ajax response

Comment: That sucks, but makes sense.  It looks like I'd need to creatively craft the command buttons on the index.php then, but make them look like they're part of status.php.        Even though I can't fire an event, is there any way at all to trigger a cgi script in a URL within the AJAX response?

Comment: You can exclude PHP from your stack - flask (python framework) is easy ways for create simple web page with some python code inside. It is only my opinion but i recommend you exclude same technologies that may be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

@hassan got me thinking, so I worked on building my command buttons on the index.php so that they're not within the ajax response.

I got them working.  The garage door opens/closes.  The index.php reloads the ajax just quick enough where the user can see the status, for example change from Closed --> Opening --> Open --> Closing --> Closed.   More importantly the page doesn't do an overall reload like the old PHP buttons were causing.

This time I did the button in HTML/javascript instead of using PHP.  Also instead of running the Python script, I'm instead using a different python-based CGI script as I mentioned is available in my OP.

Once this was working in index.php, just for the heck of it, I copied it to the status.php and when it gets loaded with ajax, it still works inside there correctly and will execute!

Here is the javascipt which first was in index.html, but ultimately moved to status.php:

```
<script>
function open_door() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.ajax( {
            url : "http://example.com/cgi-bin/myq-cgi.py?user=somethibng@hotmail.com&pass=dfgsdfgsdfg&cmd=open",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                alert ("Opening Door..."); //or use data string to show something else
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
function close_door() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $.ajax( {
            url : "http://example.com/cgi-bin/myq-cgi.py?user=something@hotmail.com&pass=dfgdfgsdfg&cmd=close",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                alert ("Closing Door..."); //or use data string to show something else
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>


<form>
<input type="button" value="open" onClick="open_door()"
</form><form>
<input type="button" value="close" onClick="close_door()"
</form>
```